# Stream output of one flux to another

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, reactive-kafka

I am getting the data from messageHandler(kafka) and processing it via servicehandler to give me some result

`serviceHandler.process(message).getMessage().toString()`

Now I need to output this stream of results so that whenever a new record comes through messagehandler, it get processed and output is pushed to front-end(angular)

```
@Autowired
MessageHandler messageHandler;
@Autowired
ServiceHandler serviceHandler;

public void runHandler() {
    Flux<Message> messages = messageHandler.flux();             
    messages.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()) 
    .doOnNext(message -> serviceHandler.process(message).getMessage().toString())
    .subscribe();
}
public Flux pushresult(){ ???? }
```

**Does anyone know of a way to what I need?**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at .map() and .flatMap().  In your case it looks like map() but if the next service you are calling also returns a Mono/Flux you want .flatMap() or you'll end up with something like:

```
Flux<Flux<String>>
```

instead of

```
Flux<String>
```

.doOnNext is meant for side effects like logging.